# Set a Bitmap as home icon in ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, bitmap, icons, actionbarsherlock

Is there a way to set a Bitmap (representing a contact photo retrieved from the address book) as the home icon in the ActionBarSherlock.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Given your `Bitmap` `bmp` just use a `BitmapDrawable` like this:

```
Resources res = getResources();
BitmapDrawable icon = new BitmapDrawable(res,bmp);
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(icon);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however the constru`BitmapDrawable(Bitmap)` is deprected [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html), I used instead `BitmapDrawable(Resource, Bitmap)`.

Comment: You're definitely right, I totally forgot about that. I'll edit my answer accordingly. Thanks ;)